# Java are there any known libraries for directory tab completion?

Tags: java, command-line

I would like to create a program in a linux/unix environment that runs from command line. The desired outcome would be to have the ability to tab complete directories. Are there any libraries available to achieve this?

Synopsis: /ho
         [tab] /home/

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/?_test=b Might be helpful for creating your own solution but I am unaware as to a direct way to solve this, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a JNI wrapper for the GNU "readline" library (which is what Bash uses for tab-completion); see http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-readline/. Tab-completion is a generic feature, not specifically tied to the filesystem — for example, the PostgreSQL command-line client uses tab-completion to complete table-names — so you'll probably want to use this in concert with the `PrefixFileFilter` that Tomasz Nurkiewicz mentions (or another similar approach for generating the list of filenames).

Answer (score 2):

[`PrefixFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/PrefixFileFilter.html) from [apache-commons](/questions/tagged/apache-commons) [IO](http://commons.apache.org/io) might be helpful:

```
File dir = new File(".");
String[] files = dir.list(new PrefixFileFilter("ho"));
```

This will return a list of files in current directory starting with `ho`. You'll get the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a library for that, just code it your self. `File` class already contains everything needed like:

- `File[] listFiles()`
- `boolean isDirectory()`
- `boolean isFile()`
- ...

Then you just need to create:

- take the temporary path, eg `"/home/Ja"`
- split it between last concrete part and part to complete, `/home` and `Ja`
- list files from concrete part `new File("/home").listFiles()`
- and select only currently correct for `partial file.getName().startsWith("Ja")`

I guess it will be around 50-100 LOCs including all the checks necessary to avoid weird things.

If you want a good approach, use [`FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html), so that you will be able to filter out files directly when invoking `listFiles`, eg

```
files = folder.listFiles(new PartialFileFilter("Ja"))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any Java libraries to create command line applications with TAB completion of directories?

You may be interested in [picocli](https://github.com/remkop/picocli). Picocli is a 1-file Java library for building command line applications with almost zero code; it can generate ANSI colored usage help messages, and picocli supports [command line autocompletion](http://picocli.info/autocomplete.html) on Linux (and Cygwin and babun on Windows) since version 1.0.

How does this work? The bash and zsh Unix shells provide something called "programmable completion", and picocli leverages this to generate an autocompletion script tailored to the `@Option` and `@Command` annotations in your application.

With this script installed, users can type the TAB key, and the Unix shell will show a list of the available subcommands and options. For options associated with a `java.io.File` or `java.nio.file.Path` field, the shell will show the available files and directories that match what the user typed so far.

This actually handles more than just files and directories: the picocli-generated completion script shows known hosts (from the user's `/etc/hosts` file) for options of type `java.net.InetAddress`, and shows `enum`values for options on fields of any enum type, including custom enums.

The below animation demonstrates what is possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recent JLine version.
The latest one is available from https://github.com/jline/jline3.
It provides built-in completers for directories and files.

Answer (score 0):

JLine is probably no longer maintained, but there are still quite a few Java projects that use it:

http://jline.sourceforge.net/index.html

However, if you know what you want to use Linux/Unix, and the only completion you want is simple file/directory names, you could just shift the problem and run your Java app under rlwrap:

```
$ rlwrap -c java ...
```